# Android EditText - allow only one decimal separator

Tags: android, android-edittext, number-formatting

I want EditText to allow only characters `0123456789.,` where both comma and dot shall be changed to some character specified by `mCurrencyFormatter.getDecimalSeparator()`. The second part is achieved by `filter(...)` method in `InputFilter` below. However, I can't force EditText to prevent second comma/dot. I wanted to do this by commented code in this class, but ofc it didn't work. I know one can just write `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` in xml file but due to a long standing android bug it always recognized decimal separator as dot. Has anyone some idea how to prevent input of second decimal separator?

InputFilter code:

```
class CurrencyInputFilter implements InputFilter {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  boolean decimalExists;

  @Override
  public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart,
      int dend) {
    sb.setLength(0);
    decimalExists = false;
    char c;
    // for (int i = 0; i < start - 1; i++) {
    // c = source.charAt(i);
    // if (Character.toString(c).equals(".") || Character.toString(c).equals(",")) {
    // decimalExists = true;
    // break;
    // }
    // }
    // if (!decimalExists) for (int i = end; i < source.length(); i++) {
    // c = source.charAt(i);
    // if (Character.toString(c).equals(".") || Character.toString(c).equals(",")) {
    // decimalExists = true;
    // break;
    // }
    // }

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      c = source.charAt(i);
      if (Character.isDigit(c)) sb.append(c);
      if ((Character.toString(c).equals(".") || Character.toString(c).equals(","))
          && !decimalExists) {
        sb.append(mCurrencyFormatter.getDecimalSeparator());
        // decimalExists = true;
      }
    }
    // decimalExists = false;
    return sb;
  }
}
```

xml of my EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:digits="0123456789.,"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone. I needed to do this programatically.

Method 1:

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true,true));
```

Method 2: (method 1 didn't work for me)

First get the default decimal separator based on device locale:

```
DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
defaultSeperator=Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator());
```

Then in your EditText TextWatcher's afterTextChanged add:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
if(editable.toString().contains(defaultSeperator))
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
else
    editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + defaultSeperator));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter) looks too complicated.
Let's simplify it and extend with one more option (required in my project).

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private final int min, max;

public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        double input = Double.parseDouble(dest.toString() + source.toString());

        if (isInRange(min, max, input)) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(int min, int max, double input) {
    return max > min
            ? input >= min && input <= max
            : input >= max && input <= min;
}}
```

Parsing inputed text to double will not let you to enter more than one dot.
Also as you see it provides an ability to filter min/max values which is absolutely necessary in most tasks.

Don't forget to attach it to your editText:

```
<your EditText>.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(min, max)});
```